# What is the set of limits of this sequence in different spaces and topologies

Tags: general-topology

What is the set of limits of the sequence $\{n^2-1:n\ge{1}\}$ in $\mathbb{R}$ with the standard topology and in $\mathbb{Q}$ with the trivial topology (indiscrete topology).

For the first case it is clear the set of limits is $\emptyset$ since the sequence diverges and $\infty\notin{\mathbb{R}}$. Apparently for the second case the set of limits is $\mathbb{Q}$ but I can't see why. I know that the trivial topology is the topology in-which the only open sets are the whole set and the empty set, in this case that would be $\mathbb{Q}$ and $\emptyset$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any sequence $\{x_n\}_n$ in any space $X$ endowed with the indescrete topology converges to any point $y\in X$.

*Proof*: If $U$ is a neighborhood of $y$, then $U=X$ so $$x_n\in X,~\forall n\in\Bbb N$$
which means that $\{x_n\}_n$ converges to $y$.